# how to write 3 diff dataframe in 3 excel worksheet in the same excel and save in r

Tags: r, excel

These 3 variables contain diff data frames as follows

"ecofst" , "Successful","Failed"

I want to write them in the same excel file but diff worksheet as listed above

here is a sample of how I want it to look like in the picture below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have data frames called `data1` and `data2` in R. Then you can use the `xlsx` package to specify the worksheet:

```
library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(data1, "file.xlsx", sheetName = "sheet1")
write.xlsx(data2, "file.xlsx", sheetName = "sheet2")
```